# Reading updated file in the Makefile function

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to read the portion of a line (some version number) from the file `version`. This functionality is added in a makefile function. Before that I am updating the file with the new version number. But when I try to assign that new version to some variable, it's reading the old version number.

Just to make sure, I have added `cat verison` command to verify the file contents.

Below are the contents of files I wrote.

file: version

```
me@linux:temp$ cat version 
PROC_V7.1.2.3
```

file: Makefile

```
me@linux:temp$ cat Makefile 
include $(shell pwd)/$(wildcard *.mk)

.PHONY: firmware
firmware:
    $(call version_replace, 100)
```

file: image.mk

```
me@linux:temp$ cat image.mk 
define version_replace
    cat version
    sed -i 's/V7/V177/g' version
    cat version
    $(eval NEW_VER:=$(shell cat version | cut -d '_' -f 2 ))
    echo $(NEW_VER)
endef
```

So when I did `make firmware` the new variable is giving the old value `V7.1.2.3` instead of `V177.1.2.3`.

```
me@linux:temp$ make firmware 
cat version
PROC_V7.1.2.3
sed -i 's/V7/V177/g' version
cat version
PROC_V177.1.2.3
NEW_VER=V7.1.2.3
echo V7.1.2.3
V7.1.2.3
```

My understanding was, all assignments executing first and `NEW_VER` is already filled with old version number when `version_replace` function is called.

So how do I read the updated version number from the file within make file function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior of `make`. The `make` will expand the recipes of a target before executing it.

The recipe `$(eval NEW_VER:=$(shell cat version | cut -d '_' -f 2 ))` will be expanded and the variable `NEW_VER` will be stored in variable list with the value V7.1.2.3 (which is from version file). Since the version is not yet updated in the version file. The recipe `echo $(NEW_VER)` will be replaced with `echo V7.1.2.3`.

Before executing, the recipes of the target `firmware` will be

```
cat version
sed -i 's/V7/V177/g' version
cat version
echo V7.1.2.3
```

Hence the output at the end is printing the older version.

> To make this work, have two different targets. One for changing version in file and other for read it.

**Makefile:**

```
all: replace_version read_version

replace_version:
    cat version
    sed -i 's/V7/V177/g' version

read_version:
    cat version
    $(eval NEW_VER:=$(shell cat version | cut -d '_' -f 2 ))
    echo $(NEW_VER)
```

> There is another possible method to make this work with single target.
>   Change the `sed` command as expandable recipe

**Makefile:**

```
firmware:
        $(call version_replace, 100)
```

**image.mk**

```
define version_replace
        $(shell sed -i 's/V7/V177/g' version)
        $(eval NEW_VER:=$(shell cat version | cut -d '_' -f 2 ))
        echo $(NEW_VER)
endef
```

Comment: Yes, variable assignment will happen sequentially after reading all the recipes, but before executing it.
In your example the value is form of direct. So the expanded recipes will be
`@echo First line
    @echo Second line`. 

`read -p "Hit return:"` will execute at the time of expanding itself.


But here the value is taken from the file, so the variable `NEW_VER` will be assigned before executing `sed -i 's/V7/V177/g' version`. Hence it is having older value.

Comment: Oh my you are right. I didn't fully expand the example in my mind :D

Answer (score 1):

Your phenomenon can be reduced to a simple albeit puzzling example:

```
MY_OUTPUT := First line
.PHONY: foo
foo:
    @echo $(MY_OUTPUT)
    $(eval MY_OUTPUT := $(shell $(info eval-time) echo Second line))
    @echo $(MY_OUTPUT)
    $(shell read -p "Hit return:")
```

Output:

```
$ make foo
eval-time
Hit return:
```

> ...*waiting for a keystroke*

```
First line
Second line
```

The evaluation of a recipe goes like this: Allocate a buffer of lines which are going to hold the final recipe command lines without make syntax. Then step through all recipe lines, execute all known make syntax, remove one level from all quotes (`$$`), do `$(eval)` stuff and write the lines into the buffer. **only then** step through the resulting list of command lines and give them out to `sh` one by one.  `$(info)` tells us that the argument string was already evaluated beforehand, breaking your intended order.

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to get `call` to work with multiple commands as you have, so I find it sometimes easier (albeit less portable perhaps) to create a shell script instead:

**Makefile**

```
EXEC := $(shell sh script.sh)
FILE := new_version
VERS := $(shell cat $(FILE))

.PHONY: firmware
firmware:
    $(info $(VERS))
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

sed 's/V7/V177/g' version | cut -d '_' -f 2 > new_version
# optional # mv new_version version
```

You can optionally overwrite the `version` file by uncommenting the last line in the script and changing the `FILE` variable in `Makefile` to `version` instead.

```
$ make firmware
V177.1.2.3
make: Nothing to be done for `firmware'.
```

Comment: Function call is working fine in my case. `cat version` output is correct. The assignment to NEW_VER is still giving older value (V7.1.2.3) even after the file updated to V177.1.2.3

Comment: Where are you setting `NEW_VER`?

Comment: In the image.mk file. `$(eval NEW_VER:=$(shell cat version | cut -d '_' -f 2 )) echo $(NEW_VER)`

Comment: There's really no need to do that with the `script.sh` method I've shown in the example. Essentially the script runs, creates a file with the updated version and then the makefile reads the result.

Comment: Hmm.. I will experiment with this and let you know. :)

Comment: I have a requirement where I need to call `version_replace` functions multiple times. like `$(call version_replace, 100)` and `$(call version_replace, 200)` etc.. This 100, 200 are the new versions which I need to replace with older versions. Update the new version to some variable so that I can use that variable at some place. Your solution gives $VERS is constant and won't update if some command replaces in the makefile the version file with new version. Sorry for troubling you. :(

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the two things like this:

```
.PHONY: firmware
firmware: version
    # replace with firmware generation command that reads from $<
    @echo FIRMWARE $@ $<

.PHONY: version
version:
    # replace with version update command (sequence)
    @echo VERSION $@
```

Building `firmware` will result in this sequence:

```bash
$ make firmware
# replace with version update command (sequence)
VERSION version
# replace with firmware generation command that reads from version
FIRMWARE firmware version
```

**EDIT:** your requirement for different version increments should be a variable that controls the command lines for the `version:` goal, e.g. `make VERSION_INCREMENT=200 firmware`.